# Powershell Script LineFeed in Messagebox

Tags: powershell, linefeed, tpm

I need help to sort the output after volume `$_.mountpoint` in the messagebox.

```
if ((Get-Tpm).TPMReady -eq $true){
    $tpminfo = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Tpm -namespace root\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftTpm
    [string]$tpmversion = $tpminfo.PhysicalPresenceVersionInfo 
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show( "TPM Enabled "+$lf+ $lf + "VOLUMES: $lf"+ `
    (Get-BitLockerVolume |select-object mountpoint,VolumeStatus| `
    ForEach-Object {$lf,$_.MountPoint, $_.VolumeStatus}))

} else {
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show( "TPM DISABLED "+$lf+ $lf + "VOLUMES: $lf"+ `
    (Get-BitLockerVolume |select-object mountpoint,VolumeStatus| `
    ForEach-Object {$lf,$_.MountPoint, $_.VolumeStatus}))

    EXIT
}
```

Thanks Mattias

Comment: I don't see a question? What is the problem your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way of inserting linefeeds instead:

```
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show( "TPM Enabled: $thing`r`nVolumes:$thing")
```

So, in your script I'd do it this way (not tested):

```
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show( "TPM DISABLED`r`n`r`nVOLUMES: `r`n" +`
    (Get-BitLockerVolume |select-object mountpoint,VolumeStatus |`
    ForEach-Object {"`r`n" + $_.MountPoint + ": " + $_.VolumeStatus}))
```

Comment: You probably don't need the `r carriage returns but sometimes you do depending on what you;re doing so I've included them for completeness